# How to wait until a CCCallBlock is finished?

Tags: cocos2d-iphone

I'm triggering several animations inside CCCallBlock. Each animation inside has a duration but the number of them is defined in runtime. In the game there's state machine and I need to wait until the last animation is finished, but I can't use this:

```
 if([self numberOfRunningActions] > 0)
```

because the action is a CCCallBlock with duration 0.

How I can set a duration for the CCCallBlock action? Is possible to do it in runtime?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It might be wrong for a lot of reasons, but I came up with this:

```
[CCCallBlock actionWithBlock:^{
         float duration = [self.cardsMatrix peepCards];
         [self runAction:[CCDelayTime actionWithDuration:duration]];
}];
```

here self is the CCLayer with the state machine that controls the game.

Answer (score 0):

`CCCallBlock` runs a `block` which is a `C` function (sort of). You can't set a duration for a function.

You can add another `CCCallBlock` to your animation, put them in a `CCSequence` and when this `CCCallBlock` runs, you know that the animation is done.

Comment: You're right but I can't add this animations without modifying several parts of the game. My code is messed up that I had to came up with the trick I posted above. Bad, too bad. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
[self runAction:[CCSequence actions:[CCCallBlock actionWithBlock:^{
    NSLog(@"my block");
}], [my next function], nil]];
```

Comment: This won't work because I have to wait until the code inside the block is finished to trigger the next function. I know how CCSequence works.